# How to group external API json data by date in silverstripe 3 template?

Tags: php, json, arraylist, silverstripe

I am able to read and display data from RestAPI using RestfulService, but not able to group this data by date value.
my current code which is working fine

```
$myList = ArrayList::create(); 
foreach ($jsonData['list'] as $result) {
   $myresult = $result;
   $myList->push($myresult);
}
```

I used GroupedList::create() on DataObject before, but how do I use this with ArrayList.

e.g. when I print $result in foreach is gives

```
Array('Id' => '123', 'Title' => 'foo', 'Date' => '2018-01-16')
Array('Id' => '124', 'Title' => 'bar', 'Date' => '2018-01-16')
Array('Id' => '125', 'Title' => 'foo-bar', 'Date' => '2018-01-16')
```

That I need to group

```
newArray['2018-01-16'][0] = array(

    Array('Id' => '123', 'Title' => 'foo', 'Date' => '2018-01-16'),
    Array('Id' => '124', 'Title' => 'bar', 'Date' => '2018-01-16'),
    Array('Id' => '125', 'Title' => 'foo-bar', 'Date' => '2018-01-16')
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the expected data structure?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for providing example data.

You can achieve this with nested ArrayLists. This is slightly more complicated than just using a PHP array, but here's an example:

```
$myList = ArrayList::create();
foreach ($jsonData['list'] as $result) {
    // Look for an existing holder list
    if (!$myList->find('Date', $result['Date'])) {
        // Create one
        $myList->push([
            'Date' => $result['Date'],
            'List' => ArrayList::create(),
        ]);
    }

    // Get the list now that we know it's there
    $subList = $myList->find('Date', $result['Date']);

    // Push the current result record into the grouped list
    $subList->List->push($result);
}
return $myList;
```

You could then loop in your template like this:

```
<% loop $GetMyList %>
    <h2>{$Date.XML}</h2>
    <ul>
    <% loop $List %>
        <li id="{$Id.ATT}">{$Title.XML}</li>
    <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: How about using a `GroupedList` on an `ArrayList`? Wouldn't that be simpler?

Comment: @Robbie Averill, Thanks for the code but in my case it gives a [Notice] Trying to get property of non-object at $subList->List->push($result);

Comment: @wmk, can you please provide silverstripe documentation link for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Given your data is like:

```
Array('Id' => '123', 'Title' => 'foo', 'Date' => '2018-01-16')
Array('Id' => '124', 'Title' => 'bar', 'Date' => '2018-01-16')
Array('Id' => '125', 'Title' => 'foo-bar', 'Date' => '2018-01-16')
```

You can, as Robbie Averill stated, put this in a SilverStripe [ArrayList](http://api.silverstripe.org/3/ArrayList.html) to work with it. As ArrayList implements the [SS_List](http://api.silverstripe.org/3/SS_List.html) interface, you can feed your ArrayList data to a [GroupedList](http://api.silverstripe.org/3/GroupedList.html) and group by a field of your data, in this case "Date". In your controller put something like:

```
/**
* @return GroupedList
**/
public function getGroupedAPIData() {

    $data = ....; //get your data...

    $myList = ArrayList::create($data);
    $groupedList = GroupedList::create($myList);

    return $groupedList;

}
```

Note: this GroupedList object doesn't know how to group the data right now, we can configure this in the template using the `GroupedBy` method. It returns another List you can loop over called `$Children`:

```
<% loop $GroupedAPIData.GroupedBy(Date) %>
    <h3>$Date</h3> 
    <ul>
        <% loop $Children %>
            <li>$Title ($ID)</li>
        <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
<% end_loop %>
```

If you need more fancy logic on the data you consume through your API you might convert the Data you get to a Subclass of ViewableData with your custom logic.

See [Grouping Lists in SilverStripe Docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/model/how_tos/grouping_dataobject_sets/)

Comment: thanks for the code but I did not tried this method because Robbie Averill code did work perfectly for me after some changes.